# preg_replace and file_get_contents - how to get ${1}?

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace, file-get-contents

I have this piece of code:

```
echo preg_replace('/\!(.*)\!/', file_get_contents('${1}'), $str);
```

What it is meant to do is replacing all `!...!` with the contents of the file specified between the exclamation marks. However, it is not working because `${1}` is not getting replaced:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(${1}) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

If I code:

```
echo preg_replace('/\!(.*)\!/', '${1}', $te);
```

everything is fine (i.e. the text between `!...!` is replaced by the text itself).

How can I make the `${1}` in `file_get_contents` also be replaced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo preg_replace_callback('/\!(.*)\!/', function($matches) {
    return file_get_contents($matches[1]);
}, $str);
```

There you go. Use preg_replace_callback for this kind of replacements, where you need to call a custom function on the matches that would give the replacement string.

Comment: Thanks, however it then opens `!...!`. It is replaced but includes the `!`. It was simple to solve though, just use `substr`.

Comment: Yep. I edited it to use `$matches[1]` after I realized the error.

Comment: Question: Does this syntax work with php 5.3? I ask because PHP 5.2.14 does not allow placing an anonymous function directly into the `preg_replace_callback` function parameter list and generates a parse error with the above code. ???

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `e` modifiert, like this:

```
echo preg_replace('/!(.*)!/e', 'file_get_contents("$1");', $str);
```

But just like the `eval()` function, this might become *evil* in some cases.

Comment: I'm not much in favour of `eval` I'm afraid.